# True/false buttons for mchoice questions with exams2moodle

Tags: r, moodle, r-exams

I am using R exams to create mchoice questions. I really would like to know if it's possible to obtain a "true" button and "false" button next to each statement with `exams2moodle` as in the following image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is on our wishlist but, currently, it is not implemented in `exams2moodle()`. There are two alternatives, though:

1. You can ask the question as a standard multiple-choice question with a single check box for each statement. Then, checking the box corresponds to "true" and not checking the box corresponds to "false".
2. Alternatively, you can ask a `cloze` question with several `schoice` sub-questions. In each sub-question you could offer two options true/false. Especially when combining this with `exams2moodle(..., cloze = list(cloze_mchoice_display = "MULTICHOICE_H"))` you will get a similar formatting to the True/False item from your question.